# Add widgets into my own application.- Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-manifest

How do I add google, facebook etc. widgets in my own application?

Answer (score 1):

If by "widgets" you mean "app widgets", you can try to use `AppWidgetHost` and `AppWidgetHostView`. These are mostly used by home screen activities.