# Configuring external android widgets programmatically

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to add few external widgets to my Activity as described in this link 
[Can I add widgets from installed apps to my application activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481503/can-i-add-widgets-from-installed-apps-to-my-application-activity)

It works fine, but everytime I start the application, it launches the configuration screens for the widgets. Is there a way to either save the configuration information once or do the configuration dynamically from the code?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out how to do this. You can add widgets programmatically only in System Apps. Otherwise you always have to use the widget chooser intent. 
I made my app as a system app, and it worked